# $ ionic cordova run android –prod gives errors

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk, platform

I would like to generate the production apk of my app with the commands

```
$ ionic cordova build android --prod
```

and
    $ ionic cordova run android --prod

But these commands gives me some errors. The entire output it's here: https://pastebin.com/iygWpnxY .
These are two error details of the ouput:

---

`Error: ./node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
at Object.getEffectiveTypeAnnotationNode
[....]
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\gitlab\veneto-app\src\app'
resolve './app.module.ngfactory'`

I've tryied to google this problem but I've found only similar errors with solution that are not usefull for me. How can I resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

backup existing node_modules folder and try reinstall node modules

> npm install

if not works reinstall android platform